# Why would ie8 center text when the text-align is set to left?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Using ie8's own dev tools it shows the elements text-align value as left, but it is rendered centered in ie8 standards mode.
In quirks or ie7 standards, everything is correctly aligned left.

[image: Screenshot of IE Developer tools illustrating the issue]

Comment: How does it look in other browsers?

Comment: Instead of an image your best bet would be to post a SSCCE like example. The minimum amount of code you (and we) need to reproduce the same problem. Code can be posted by copypasting, selecting it and hitting the "code" (that binary image) button.

Comment: In all other browsers I've tested (opera, fx 2-3.5, chrome, safari) it correctly inherits the text-align:left from the class applied to the table.

The image was simply to show that ie8's dev tools indicate it should align left yet doesn't.

As for enough code to illustrate it, see: http://pastie.org/685460

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A very elegant solution from [haslayout.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318094642/http://haslayout.net/css/Non-Inherited-TH-Text-Align-Bug):

```
th {
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your head tag

```
<style>th{text-align: left; font-weight:normal;}</style>
```

If you have other tables on the page which you do not want to be affected by this change then you can apply a class to your table and style the elements of that table.

```
... <table class='work_in_IE'> ...


<style type="text/css">.work_in_IE  th{ text-align: left; font-weight:normal;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-align is hereditary.  Does the parent tag (TABLE, I think) center text?

Comment: The table has a class setting text-align to left. The <th> does not inherit this.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the <th> element will still center and bold the text due to the browser's internal styling. This being a big reason why I've recently started using CSS Reset sheets in all my projects.

Comment: This could be the issue. ie8 is not inheriting from the table tag.
I need to specifically state the rule for th to work in ie8.

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot get the answer you could try 
th { float: left; } 
it works fine for me.